# How to properly use a binding in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to bind the background of a WPF Rectangle to the Brush property of another element.

The initialization looks like this:

```
MazeElement nextElement = new MazeElement();
nextElement.Position = new Point(xIndex, yIndex);
nextElement.BackgroundColor = Brushes.Aqua;
MazeElements.Add(nextElement);

Binding bg = new Binding {Source = MazeElements[Index(xIndex, yIndex)]};

Rectangle nextRect = new Rectangle();
nextRect.Height = MazeGridSize;
nextRect.Width = MazeGridSize;
nextRect.Fill = Brushes.White;
nextRect.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
nextRect.StrokeThickness = 2;

nextRect.SetBinding(Shape.FillProperty, bg);

temp.Children.Add(nextRect);
Canvas.SetLeft(nextRect, xIndex * MazeGridSize);
Canvas.SetTop(nextRect, yIndex * MazeGridSize);
```

Where is my mistake? I don't understand how to use the Binding from the C# side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are not providing us with enough information. We cannot see the full nature of the type MazeElement. But I assume that the BackgroundColor is a Property on the MazeElement class

Second, the binding has a Source, an object in your case nextElement, and the a PropertyPath, in your case the BackgroundColor. Therefore your binding object should be:

```
Binding bg = new Binding {Source = nextElement, Path = new PropertyPath("BackgroundColor") };
```

In your case the source property is of the same type as the target dependency property, so the above will do what you want. If it was not the case, you can set a converter on the binding - Look that up, if you need that in another situation

Comment: >I assume that the BackgroundColor is a Property on the MazeElement class
Ah, sorry for that...
Yes you are right, BackgroundColor is the Property I was talking about, its type is a Brush

And very much thank you for that fast answer :)